# Windows XP Stuck at Manufacturer Splash, Multicolored Lines Appear

Tags: windows-xp, boot, motherboard

Title is pretty self-explanatory. When I boot this old Dell tower with any monitor (VGA of course), well the first time I tried to boot it nothing happened on the monitor. When I rebooted it from that state it did as the title states. It gets to the Dell logo and then multicolored lines appear kind of spazz out until the screen goes essentially black with few multicolored specs.

I think this is a hardware issue but I need to salvage this PC and get it going again. Is there any way I can fix this? Maybe the mobo battery has died?

EDIT: After powering off from the multicolored lines state it won't register anything on the monitor. It emits 4 beeps and then 2 beeps.

EDIT: It alternates between reboot cycling from the windows logo and after a few cycles it is beeping and displaying a black monitor. Front lights display 3,4, during black screen and beeping. Trying to initiate that sequence again so I can write down the beeps

EDIT: It ran CHDISC check or something... Now it displays the lights, (1, 3, 4) which apparently is not a proper code. Black screen.

BEEPING SEQUENCE: Emits 1 long beep, 1 long beep, 2 short beeps, 2 short beeps. I realize this isn't exactly a proper code so I'm not sure if I'm just interpretting the beeps incorrectly. The way I recorded the beeps above is the way I heard them.

Comment: If those beeps represent the error, they would represent RAM failure on most Dell computers.

Comment: @JakeGould Ideally the computer would be bootable. Should I try different ram?

Comment: What is the model of this Dell computer?

Comment: @DavidPostill Dell Dimension 3100

Comment: @Kirurgo There is no 4-2 beep code. https://i.imgur.com/Fyvq1Q3.png. Screenshot from [Dell™ Dimension™ 3100/E310 Service Manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_dimension_desktops/dimension-3100_service%20manual_en-us.pdf)

Comment: @Kirurgo Check the Diagnostic Lights on the front panel. See the manual in my previous comment for the meaning of the lights.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know how or why but it doesn't get stuck anymore. It just infinitely reboots. This is after I left the pc for a couple of days. I don't understand why it would suddenly change behaviors. I did nothing different. I guess I'll go google troubleshooting for infinite reboot cyle. I believe it's fixable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It does flash the lights 3,4, while starting. Does that mean it's a memory issue like a previous commentor supposed?

EDIT: I left it to reboot cycle while I was looking up troubleshooting and then it began beeping and displayed the 3,4 lights. I didn't note the beeping pattern but I definitely believe it's the ram, Thank you!

Comment: @Kirurgo Yes. 3,4 is memory failed. Instructions in the manual.

Comment: @Kirurgo Answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It does flash the lights 3,4, while starting

This indicates a memory failure:

> Memory modules are detected, but a memory failure has 
>   occurred.
>
> - If you have two or more memory modules installed, remove the 
>     modules, reinstall one module (see "Memory"), and then restart the 
>     computer. If the computer starts normally, reinstall an additional module. 
>     Continue until you have identified a faulty module or reinstalled all 
>     modules without error.
> - If available, install properly working memory of the same type into your computer (see "Memory").
> - If the problem persists, contact Dell for technical assistance.

[image]

Source [Dell™ Dimension™ 3100/E310 Service Manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_dimension_desktops/dimension-3100_service%20manual_en-us.pdf)